# Update primary key Django MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, primary-key

I try to update the PK in Django with the `.save()` method, but when I save the object, Django duplicates the object with the same data but a different PK. For example:

```
from gestion_empleados.Models import Empleados
>>> e = Empleados.objects.get(pk="56789034U")
>>> e.pk
u'56789034U'
>>> e.pk = "11111111L"
>>> e.save()
>>> e.pk
'11111111L'
>>> e2 = Empleados.objects.get(pk="56789034U")
>>> e2
<Empleados: Juan 56789034U>
>>> e
<Empleados: Juan 11111111L>
```

The objects are the same with different PKs, and I want to change the PK without duplicating the object.

Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think Django allows you to change the object's primary key. You may have to delete the original object.

```
e2.delete()
```

According to the Django docs

> The primary key field is read-only. If you change the value of the primary key on an existing object and then save it, a new object will be created alongside the old one.

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#primary-key)

Comment: I think to delete the original object but is strange that django don´t permit update PK, thanks!

Comment: `.update()` will work for changing a PK. I posted an example below.

Answer (score 3):

Django's `Model.save()` method relies on whether there's already a row with the same PK in your db to decide if it should issue an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query.

As a more general rule: while it's *technically* possible to modify a PK at the SQL level, it's no necessarily such a good idea, as it means you'd have to update all related rows in all related tables (ok, still technically possible but really not a sane idea as far as I'm concerned), AND warn all applications depending on this PK of the change too - and then good luck. To make a long story short: it's always safer to consider PKs as immutable (and that's why quite a few people in the SQL world favor surrogate primary keys even when there's a seemingly obvious natural one).

Comment: The problem here is that Django tries to be DB-agnostic, and hence doesn't support CASCADE UPDATE, which is the sane way to update a natural key.

Comment: @DylanYoung as far as I'm concerned the only "sane" way is to have immutable, non reusable primary keys. Try a cascade update on real-life sized dataset and you'll find out why it's not a viable solution. Also, it will only update the database content itself, not any external data that depend on it (and it's a very common situation to have external apps depending on your database pks).

Comment: Thank your stars you aren't managing a database that needs to migrate primary keys then :)

Comment: FYI: every database I know reuses serial primary keys. Using UUIDs can have a substantial performance impact. Is that sane?

Comment: Except for buggy dbms (https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,643901,643904#msg-643904), I never saw a dbms reusing serial pks (at least not without someone messing with the counters). And the reason I don't have to manage a db that needs to migrate pks is that I made sure I wouldn't have any reason to do so - not anymore that is (been here, done that, now I know better).

Comment: Again, all implementations of serial keys wrap around that I've seen.  I'd be happy if you showed one that didn't (maybe a python-based DB using arbitrary sized integers? Sounds...slow).  Lucky you; other people work in the real world where the state of almost all software systems are frightfully close to total collapse.

Comment: Well, looks like I've been working in some imaginary world for 20+ years now, using imaginary db systems.

Comment: No. You're lucky that you have full control over your DB, never needed to combine multiple systems/tables that used serial PKs, never used a flawed GUID implementation, etc... There are a million uses for changing a primary key. Get over yourself.

Comment: If you're talking about deep refactoring / restructuration, moving data from one system to another (with of course totally incompatible schema) etc  then of course there are reasons to mess with primary keys here - and I wrote my own share of (sometimes very complex) data migration scripts. What I meant is that the only reasons for primary key changes were purely technical and only the domain of such migration scripts - the schema itself should not mandate it (pks should be choosen so they should not have to change for business domain reasons) and application code has no business changing PKs.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just run a filter/update:

```
Empleados.objects.filter(pk=e.pk).update(pk='11111111L')
```

As an added bonus to being simpler, it'll also run significantly faster than a delete + insert

Answer (score -1):

First you should make sure that the object with the primary key "11111111L" has been added to your table. Probably doing something along the lines of:

> > > e3 = Empleados.objects.get(pk="11111111L")

And then making sure that e3 contains . Once you confirm that it is there, then you can just use the following statement to get rid of the object with the primary key "56789034U" (assuming you keep e2 around):

> > > e2.delete()