# Editing a primary key in DJango

Tags: python, django, postgresql, admin, primary-key

I registered a model on DJango admin app to be able to edit its entries.
"`admin.site.register(model)`"
However DJango treats PK as read-only so when trying to edit it, it duplicates the entry and ignores any reference to it by Foreign keys.

The primary key field is read-only. If you change the value of the primary key on an existing object and then save it, a new object will be created alongside the old one. You can look at [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/)  to know what I mean.

Is there anyway to be able to edit the primary key in a certain model and cascade the update to any reference to it by foreign keys?

This is models.py

```
class Cabinet(models.Model):
    mac_address = models.CharField(max_length=17, primary_key=True)

class FailureLog(models.Model):
    mac_address = models.ForeignKey(Cabinet)
```

This is admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Cabinet)
```

In the admin app, I can't change the primary key of Cabinet without duplicating it and loosing all reference to the FailureLog

Comment: What are you trying to edit it for?..

Comment: No, you will lose the connection when you change a primary key. This is why you should choose your primary key something that is not identifiable by end users, such as a sequential id or a UNID so that you will never need to change it.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29657636/1757321 Might help

Comment: @Sayse I was editing a typo

Comment: @Selcuk I am working on an existing project and I can't change the design now. Isn't there a way to edit the primary key because if I delete the old duplicate I lose all reference to it by foreign keys