Django change on_delete at runtime
Story
I am making a Jurnal app. Currently working on synchronization across multiple machines. I want to synchronize model by model, not the whole database at once. I even allow synchronization of just a few entries, image:

The current problem I am facing is replacing the data of a model with the new synchronized data. I have the new database for the model (not all models) in JSON.
Other models have ForeginKey to the data being changed (with on_delete=CASCADE). I have a mapping as a dict {old_pk : new_pk...}. I will use that to update other objects ForeginKeys to the objects being synchronized (whose pks will change).
Problem
I want to delete the old database without CASCADEing the deletion. I would like to set on_delete to DO_NOTHING temporarily until I finish the migration.
Note: ReadAt code contains:
read_by = models.ForeignKey(
    Person,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, # change temporarily to DO_NOTHING at runtime
)

By changing on_delete at runtime I could do:
# DELETE OLD DATA
ReadAt.on_delete=DO_NOTHING # pseudo code I want to achieve

Person.objects.all().delete()  # without code above, this deletes all ReadAt

# LOAD NEW DATA
with open("person_file.json", mode="w+", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    myfile.write(json.dumps(data_new_server))
call_command("loaddata", "person_file.json")

# Then fix the PKs of ReadAt with a mapping I have made

ReadAt.on_delete=CASCADE # pseudo code, change back
# ideally check the integrity of ReadAt data now

Alternative
I thought of this, but got stuck:

Find the max of imported pk MAX_PK.
Change all PKs entries in Person (and FK in ReadAt), add MAX_PK to them.

I don't know how to do this. pk seems uneditable, This doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77775898/5057078


Import new data (there is no overlap between the old and new data).
Change the PK of ReadAt from old_PK to new_PK.
Delete all Person whose PK >= MAX_PK, there are no ForeginKeys to them after the previous step.


You cannot easily (and arguably should not) change on_delete at runtime, as it requires a schema migration to take effect in the database. To do this programmatically in Django, you'd have to prepare the migration files ahead of time and then invoke them as done from a management command or similar. It's not a recommended way of doing things.

You may want to look into prior art for synchronizing data, e.g. CRDTs.

Also, using integer primary keys will make your life very hard when there are multiple machines, as they will inevitably have "reused" those primary keys without knowing about each other. I would recommend ULIDs (or UUIDv7).

@AKX In my case, integer PKs is not a problem. When syncing I choose "Keep both" option in my migration and then they are renumbered.

You wouldn't have to renumber anything if you used non-integer PKs...

@AKX I might look into this later. The application is a bit bigger and I would like to avoid migration before I finish the synchronization, as I need to sync the data.

I thought of this, but it seems more complicated than what I want. It originates from the alternative in the question:
Additional constraints on the solution:

re-number the pks after finished
Only two machines are ever used, so they will only sync between them.

Solution:
# 1. Find the max of current pk MAX_PK_CURRENT.
max_pk_current = max(p.pk for p in models.Person.objects.all())
# 2. Find the max of imported pk MAX_PK_IMPORTED.
max_pk_imported = max(d["pk"] for d in data_new_server)
# 3. MAX_PK = max(MAX_PK_CURRENT, MAX_PK_IPORTED)
max_pk = max(max_pk_current, max_pk_imported) + 1
# 4. Make a tmp Person with PK=MAX_PK
    # TODO assuming it exists
    # get a Person
    # make JSON
data_str = serializers.serialize("json", (models.Person.objects.first(),))
data = json.loads(data_str)
data[0]["pk"] = max_pk
data[0]["fields"]["display_name"] = "TMP PERSON"
data_str = json.dumps(data)
    # write to a file
with open("merge_file.json", mode="w+", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    myfile.write(data_str)
    # import the file
call_command("loaddata", "merge_file.json")
# 5. A list of ReadAt pk mapping readat_mapping {ReadAt_pk : Person_pk}
read_at_mapping = {}
# 6. Change the PK of ReadAt from old_PK to MAX_PK.
for r in models.ReadAt.objects.all():
    read_at_mapping[r.pk] = r.read_by_id
    r.read_by_id = max_pk
    r.save()
# 7. Delete all Person whose PK < MAX_PK, there are no ForeginKeys to them after the previous step.
models.Person.objects.filter(pk__lt=max_pk).delete()
# 8. Import new data (there is no overlap between the duplicate and imported data).
with open("merge_file.json", mode="w+", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    myfile.write(json.dumps(data_new_server))
    # import the file
call_command("loaddata", "merge_file.json")
# 9. Change the PK of ReadAt from MAX_PK to pk provided by mapping.
#    new_pk = mapping_server[readat_mapping[ReadAt_pk]] (or something like that).
for r in models.ReadAt.objects.all():
    m_r = read_at_mapping[r.pk]
    if m_r in mapping_server:
        m_r = mapping_server[m_r]
    if m_r == None:
        r.delete()
        continue
    r.read_by_id = m_r
    r.save()
# 10. Delete tmp Person, there are no ForeginKeys to it after the previous step.
models.Person.objects.filter(pk=max_pk).delete()

Note: I don't get why Python highlight doesn't work here...
